# git diff treats file as newly added when using "-- <path>" flag

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

Noticed a strange behavior of `git diff`:

I want to diff a few of my working files with HEAD, say `dir/a.h` and `dir/a.cc`.

When I use `git diff HEAD` it works well, but there are more than these 2 files I have changed. So I changed the command to `git diff HEAD -- * a.*`.
Surprisingly it can not find those 2 files in HEAD and treat them as newly added.

```
$ git diff --stat HEAD
 dir/a.cc |   32 ++++++++++----------------
 dir/a.h  |   12 +++++-----
 2 files changed, 18 insertions(+), 26 deletions(-)

$ git diff --stat HEAD -- *a.*
 dir/a.cc |  208 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 dir/a.h  |  142 ++++++++++++++++++
 2 files changed, 350 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

=======================================================================

Update: to avoid anything special to my code base, I added a new directory and 2 new files just for testing.

First I committed dir2/b.h and dir2/b.cc, both files only has one line of content.
Then I made small changes to these files and test git diff.

This is correct behavior:

```
$ git diff --stat HEAD 
 dir2/b.cc |    2 +-
 dir2/b.h  |    2 +-
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

This is also correct:

```
$ git diff --stat HEAD -- dir2/*b.*
 dir2/b.cc |    2 +-
 dir2/b.h  |    2 +-
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

But this is strange (treats both files as new):

```
$ git diff --stat HEAD -- *b.*
 dir2/b.cc |    1 +
 dir2/b.h  |    1 +
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

@Chronial, I'm in root dir of my repo.
@jszakmeister, as these 2 files are just new, seems it's not related to rename/move...

"git status" is correct:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   dir2/b.cc
#       modified:   dir2/b.h
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I think it might be a problem related to bash "*" matching. But still don't understand the behavior...

Comment: this is probably related to the fact that you are not in the root of your repo. Try to reproduce that in the root of your repo.

Comment: Why would this have anything to do with being at the root of the repo?  I suspect it's because `a.cc` and `a.h` are seen as either renames, or based on some history of another file.  And narrowing the path is probably limiting the copy/rename detection.  @Kai what does git status say?